# Pandas out of memory error when applying regex function

Tags: python, regex, pandas, memory

I want to apply a regex function to clean text in a dataframe column.

ie:

```
re1 = re.compile(r'  +')

def fixup(x):
    x = x.replace('#39;', "'").replace('amp;', '&').replace('#146;', "'").replace(
        'nbsp;', ' ').replace('#36;', '$').replace('\\n', "\n").replace('quot;', "'").replace(
        '<br />', "\n").replace('\\"', '"').replace('<unk>','u_n').replace(' @.@ ','.').replace(
        ' @-@ ','-').replace('\\', ' \\ ')
    return re1.sub(' ', html.unescape(x))

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(fixup).values.astype(str)
```

However when I run this I get a 'MemoryError' (in jupyter notebook).

I have 128GB of RAM and file to create the dataframe was 4GB.

Also I can see from profiler meory use is <20% when this error is thrown.

The error message give no more detail than 'MemoryError:' at the line I apply the fixup function.

Any ideas to help debug?

Comment: Your code runs without error on a few small test cases I tried.  To debug you might try: running smaller random samples of your data to see if you always get the error; use a for loop (with `iterrows()`) instead of `apply` and use `print` statements to figure out where the error occurs; try running with only one of the `x.replace()` methods in the chain, then two, then three, etc.  If you have really long strings I guess it's possible that keeping track of so many replacements is causing some memory issues (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the `replace` chain into individual `replace` operations. Not only that will make your code more readable and maintainable, but the intermediate results will be discarded immediately after use, instead of being kept until all modifications are done:

```
replacements = ('#39;', "'"), ('amp;', '&'), ('#146;', "'"), ...
for replacement in replacements:
    x = x.replace(*replacement)
```

P.S. Shouldn't `'amp;'` be `'&amp;'`?